# psycopg2 insert multiple raw string formatting

Tags: python, sql-insert, psycopg2

I am trying to format a `insert` query string for multiple rows but also with `ON CONFLICT`. I got all mixed up with formatting arguments.

```
ses_crud_sql = """INSERT INTO session_crud(orgid, appid, sessionid, userid, customlabel, uploadedon) 
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
    ON CONFLICT (orgid, appid) 
    DO UPDATE SET customlabel = array_append(customlabel, '%(label_name)s') WHERE sessionid=sessionid
    """
    ses_crud_rows = [(org_id, app_id, sessionid, userid, str({label_name}), datetime.strftime(current_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
                     for sessionid in session_ids]
    cursor.executemany(ses_crud_sql, ses_crud_rows)
```

I need to insert multiple rows for every session in `session_ids` list.

So I also want to add `%(label_name)s` but this gives me

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: argument formats can't be mixed
```

Comment: The error message tells you what the problem is, you cannot mix `format`(%s) and `pyformat`(%(label_name)s) parameter formats. You need to pick one or the other. Also not sure what this, `str({label_name}` is supposed to be doing?